# Constructing an SAT formula from a Clique graph

Tags: np-complete, np, 3-sat, clique

We were given this practice question to do in a lecture and its solution afterwards. I have spent hours upon hours trying to understand the solution but still do not understand.
From my knowledge when we are reducing SAT to clique we don't focus on its compliment, so why are we trying to derive the formula from the compliment graph? It also seems strange that they randomly chose 4 vertices to label (P, R, S ¬Q) then derive the rest of the labels from there? Is this the general process we use when reducing Clique to SAT, even for 3SAT?

If anyone can help explain the solution because I have watched multiple videos on reducing clique to SAT, asked ChatGPT, looked at many stack resources but I am still very confused. There's isn't much on the reverse either (Clique to SAT)

This is the question:
[image]

This is the solution:
[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't get too trapped in this question as it is only an example. Let's think about the general case. How can we build a formula $\varphi(G, k)$ out of a graph $G$ and an integer $k$ such that $G$ has a $k$-clique if, and only if, $\varphi(G, k)$ is satisfiable? Here's a general construction:

We start by constructing variables $x_{v, i}$ for $i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$ and $v \in V(G)$. They will represent that vertex $v$ is the $i$-th vertex in the desired clique. We first need to force that each position $i$ in the clique is used by some vertex, so we add clauses:
$$
\bigvee_{v \in V(G)} x_{v, i}, \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}.$$

We also need to forbid a vertex $v$ from using more than one position, by adding clauses of the form:

$$
\overline{x_{v, i}} \lor \overline{x_{v, j}}, \quad \forall i \neq j \in \{1, \ldots, k\}. 
$$

Now let us construct variables $y_v$ that state that vertex $v$ is part of the clique, so we have $$y_v \iff (x_{v, 1} \lor \ldots \lor x_{v, k}),$$ which can be written with the following clauses:
$$
\overline{y_v} \lor x_{v_1} \ldots \lor x_{v, k}
$$
and
$$
\overline{x_{v, i}} \lor y_v, \quad \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}.
$$

Now we need to enforce that if $y_v$ and $y_u$ then indeed $(u,v) \in E(G)$.
This can be done by creating clauses of the form
$$\overline{y_v} \lor \overline{y_u}, \quad \forall u \neq v \text{ s.t. } (u,v) \not\in E(G).$$

What the solution is suggesting, is that instead of thinking of a clique in $G$ you can think of an "independent set" in $\overline{G}$. Then, we can encode things in a similar fashion, with variables $z_{v, i}$ representing that vertex $v$ is the $i$-th of the desired independent set. Now, if $(u, v) \in E(\overline{G})$, then we add clauses of the form
$$
\overline{z_{v, i}} \lor \overline{z_{u, j}}, \quad \forall i \neq j \in \{1, \ldots, k\},
$$
for every edge $(u, v) \in E(\overline{G})$. Which encoding will be smaller depends on whether $|E(G)|$ is smaller than $|E(\overline{G})|$ or not.